# What is a simple, reversible, non-cryptographic string cypher function with excellent avalanching?

Tags: javascript, c#, encryption

I need to implement a pair of functions to obfuscate / deobfuscate a string, in the form:

- `string cipher(string plainText, string secret)`
- `string decipher(string cipherText, string secret)`

I need them to be **terse** and simple to implement. I am hoping for e.g. about a page of code or less that I will embed in my code body with **no special dependencies**. I will need to implement this in C# and **vanilla** JavaScript in-browser.

This does not need to be cryptographically secure; it is totally OK if it is *trivial* to hack.

Most of all I am looking for a function with excellent **avalanching**, i.e. small changes to the plain text input result in drastically different cipher text output.

I am considering a few possibilities, including XTEA and [NTSA](https://www.mdpi.com/2073-8994/11/2/293/pdf). But what I have seen so far is small changes e.g. to the end of the plain text result only in (somewhat) small changes to the end of the cipher text. Hence the changes appear to be localized. This is not great for my use, where the plain text will include an ever-incrementing timestamp as its main source of entropy.

What is a good function or algorithm to achieve this, without resorting to large bodies of code or dependencies?

Comment: Is the JS running in the browser? Or server-side?

Comment: What if you put the timestamp at the start? The instinct is to put it at the back.
But by nature changes at the front should have a stronger avalancing effect then stuff at the back. You could of course also add salting to the process.

Comment: @mjwillis this would be in the browser, in an SPA

Comment: How long do you want a hacker to spend decrypting the message?  The better the encryption method the longer it will take a hacker to decrypt the data.  Standard encryption method are very difficult for hacker to decrypt.  Simple encryption can be done with very little code, but it will be very simple for a hacker to decrypt.

Comment: @jdweng for my purposes, difficulty to hack is not relevant, trivial hacking is fine.

Comment: You would need to use a shift register approach similar to calculating a CRC.  See : http://www.sunshine2k.de/articles/coding/crc/understanding_crc.html

Answer (score 0):

I think I have decided on XXTEA prefaced with a random number **salt** prefix, which appears to give excellent avalanching. Thank you @Christopher for reminding me about this technique.